# installing webcam driver on acer 5740 laptop

Tags: 13.04, webcam

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit on my Acer 5740(laptop) i3 processor.  My webcam is not working.

Which driver is required to install so as to make my webcam work properly?

Comment: Why the backtrack tag?